# When I set up a react native project, it gives a MODULE_NOT_FOUND error, what is the reason?

Tags: react-native

/*it says chalk not found how do i fix this*/
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:361
throw err;
^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\sefal\Desktop\react-native\deneme\AwesomeProject\node_modules\chalk\source'. Please 
verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry       
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:353:19) 
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:566:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)   
    at _chalk (C:\Users\sefal\Desktop\react-native\deneme\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\banner.js:9:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sefal\Desktop\react-native\deneme\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\banner.js:23:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\sefal\\Desktop\\react-native\\deneme\\AwesomeProject\\node_modules\\chalk\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'chalk'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

To create a react app I ran:

```
npx create-react-app frontend --template typescript
```

Then I got this output:

```
Need to install the following packages:
create-react-app
Ok to proceed? (y)
```

And then I entered `y` and got the same error

Try running

```
npm install create-react-app
```

manually to avoid using `C:\Users\sefal\Desktop\react-native\deneme\AwesomeProject\node_modules\chalk\source` module and then run

```
npx create-react- app my-app
```

to create a react app